# Consulta en Access

Tags: ms-access

Estimados: estoy queriendo llevar a cabo una acción que realmente no sé si se puede realizar.

Esta es la consulta básica:

```
SELECT AFILIADOS, COUNT(LEGAJOS) AS TOTAL_REGISTROS, COUNT(DOCUMENTO) AS TOTAL_DOCUMENTO,
SUM(CUOTA_SOCIAL) AS TOTAL_CUOTA
FROM TABLA_1
GROUP BY AFILIADOS
```

hasta ahí sale todo bien. es algo sencillo. traigo a todos los afiliados y en la consulta resultante tengo los subtotales de cada afiliado

pero necesito algo más, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT AFILIADOS, COUNT(LEGAJOS) AS TOTAL_REGISTROS, COUNT(DOCUMENTO) AS TOTAL_DOCUMENTO,
SUM(CUOTA_SOCIAL) AS TOTAL_CUOTA, AVG(TOTAL_REGISTROS / CUOTA_SOCIAL) AS PORCENTAJE
FROM TABLA_1
GROUP BY AFILIADOS
```

en negrita marqué lo que quiero hacer: tomar esos campos que creé (total_registros y cuota_social) y utilizarlos, dentro de la misma consulta, para realizar un cálculo con ambos.

No me toma esos campos nuevos, como si no existieran ¿alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Da algún error, muestra datos en blanco? ¿Esas columnas tienen datos? Si es posible muestra la estructura actual de tu tabla pulsando en [edit].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185043/how-to-use-a-calculated-column-to-calculate-another-column-in-the-same-view  es en inglés pero da rewpuestas para Oracle y SQL, tal vez funciona para Ud.  Usan nested queries, CROSS APPY o Common Table Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Select afiliados, sum(total_registros) as TotalRegistros,     sum(total_documentos) as TotalDocumentos,
Sum(cuota_social) as CuotaSocial,
Avg(total_registros/total_cuota) as porcentaje
From
(Select afiliados, count(legajos) as total_registros, count(documento)     as total_documentos,
Sum(cuota_social) as total_cuota
From tabla
Group by afiliados) T
Group by afiliados;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es un select dentro del From original devolviendo un conjunto de resultados que puede manejarse como si fuera una tabla, posteriormente es a este conjunto de resultados sobre el que se hace la consulta que deseas

Comment: Hola podrias decirme si esta solucion te fue util